# Springdata Elasticsearch - How to populate id field in _source when indexing?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a document

```java
@Document(indexName = "my_index")
public class MyDocument {
  @Id
  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
  private String id;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
  private String otherField;

  ...
}
```

And a repository

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyDocument, String> {
}
```

when I do `repository.save(document);` (where document id is empty, so that a new one is generated, and 'otherValue' is set to 'someValue'), I see the following response to `es/my_index/_search?pretty`:

```json
...
"hits" : [
{
 "_index" : "my_index",
 "_type" : "_doc",
 "_id" : "AUTO_GENERATED_ID",
 "_score" : 1.0,
 "_source" : {
    "_class" : "a.b.c.MyDocument",
    "otherField": "someValue"
 }
}
]
```

The result of the `save` method is returning a java object with id field set and of course if I retrieve the document through the repository, the id is being populated in the java object and I can access it.

However, the document itself does not contain the field "id" inside source.
**How can i achieve this** while I let the ES/Springdata handle the auto-generation of Ids?

I need this because I want to apply some sorting based on other fields and the id. As a workaround I wanted to do it on "_id", but I get the following warning in the console: `299 loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of the documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled`

PS: If I do some modifications on the document retrieved from the repository and `save` it again, the document will now have the "id" field populated, but this means that I would have to double the operations on ES while trying to index a document.

---

- springdata-elasticsearch version: 4.4.5
- es version: 7.17.7

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of Spring Data Elasticsearch is that the value of the id property is written to the document source by default, since version 5.1 this can be explicitly **disabled** by adding `storeIdInSource = false` to the `@Document` annotation.

But this value will only be written into the source of the Elasticsearch if it is set on the entity. In your case, you have a `null` id property, so there is nothing that Spring Data Elasticsearch can write into document that i sent to Elasticsearch. The id is created by Elasticsearch when the save without an explicit id comes in, and only on returning the stored value or when later searching the entity's property will be filled with the id returned from Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch cannot on saving create a new id and store that somewhere in the document's source.

So if you need the id field in the source as well, you need to create some id by yourself and set it on the entity before saving it.

By the way, Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.5 is an old version that is out of maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I was debugging and inspecting the source code and came to the same conclusion. Will work on a different solution then.
Thank you again for the time spent to explain this! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding the default constructor of `MyDocument` with something like:

```java
public MyDocument {
    this.id = org.elasticsearch.common.UUIDs.base64UUID();
}
```

which basically uses the ID generator used by Elasticsearch,
and since the field is populated on the document, the value will be indexed in the `_source`.